# Does Symfony 4 load the environment variables on every request in the "prod" environment?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Does Symfony 4 somehow save or cache the environment variable parameters in the "prod" environment or does it retrieve them on every request?

My problem is that when I host my Symfony application using Apache, I need to list all the environment variables by defining them all in the `VirtualHost` configuration using `SetEnv` directives; and I would prefer not having to do that.

I would expect that when using the PHP CLI, I could "compile" the Symfony project by capturing or caching the parameters so that when the application is run through Apache, it uses these "cached" parameters.

Is it doable or the `SetEnv` approach is the only one?

Comment: Yes, Symfony always uses the current env values on each request.  No caching.  Easy enough to get around.  Don't use env variables.  Just define parameters which is what Symfony used back in the good ole days.  Parameter values will end up being compiled into the container.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony uses [the DotEnv component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html) to deal with environment variables.

The DotEnv component reads `.env` files and load its contents on environment variables.

- If there is a `.env` file, this one is loaded first. If **there is no** `.env`, file, but a `.env.dist` file exists, this one is used in its place .
- If a `.env.local` file exists, it is loaded now. This file should never be committed to a source code repository, and its values **override** those in the previous files
- If an even more localized `.env.$env.local` exists (or if it doesn't but `.env.$env` exist), is loaded now. Again, these values override those that came before.

This will populate all the declared environment variables, **but it won't override existing environment variables**. There is performance hit from reading `.env` files, but hit is practically negligible.

That these are loaded depend on the [`bootstrap.php`](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.2/config/bootstrap.php) file, that is loaded by default on `public/index.php` and `bin/console`; so the approach serves **both** HTTP request and console applications, so you could use to store these values instead of using `SetEnv` directives in your Apache configuration.

---

But wait, there is more...

On top of the above, [you can dump all these variables into a PHP-optimised file](https://symfony.com/doc/master/configuration.html#configuring-environment-variables-in-production) so that the `.env` files need not to be parsed on each request.

To do that, you simply execute:

```
composer dump-env prod
```

This will create a `.env.local.php` file. And if this file exists, none of the above will be read at all.